Spring Boot and ActiveMQ Classic retry from OpenWire JMS client
I use Spring Boot with Java 17 and ActiveMQ Classic 6.1.2. When an exception occurs I want to retry with delay 60 seconds. The problem is that every time an exception is thrown in my application, the number of retries is 7 and there is no delay between them.
Could you please check my code?
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class JmsConfig {


    @Value("${jms.activemq.brokerUrl}")
    private String brokerUrl;

    @Value("${jms.activemq.user}")
    private String brokerUsername;

    @Value("${jms.activemq.password}")
    private String brokerPassword;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory();
        factory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        factory.setUserName(brokerUsername);
        factory.setPassword(brokerPassword);
        factory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setTransactionManager(new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory));
        factory.setConcurrency("1-1");
        return factory;
    }
}

The code below is in my service:
@JmsListener(destination = "test")
@Transactional
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 4, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 60000))
public void receiveMessage(ObjectMessage message) throws JMSException {
    LOG.info("receiveMessage started......");
    try {
        .......
    } catch (JMSException | ClassCastException e) {
        LOG.error("Error while processing the message", e);
        throw e;
    }
}


last version 6.1.2

Try setting the RedeliveryPolicy on your instance of ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory, e.g.:
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory();
        factory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        factory.setUserName(brokerUsername);
        factory.setPassword(brokerPassword);
        factory.setTrustAllPackages(true);
        RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
        redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(60000);
        factory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
        return factory;
    }

